# Google people.listDirectoryPeople() method on python returns a slightly different list everytime

Tags: python, google-people-api

My organisation uses Google G Suite and contact details of all the employees are saved on the workspace directory. I've enabled people API for my work email (since it's part of G Suite) and tried listing out all employee contact details using people.listDirectoryPeople method.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    
    src = 'DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE'

    results = service.people().listDirectoryPeople(
        readMask='names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,organizations',
        sources=src,
        pageSize=1000
    ).execute()

    directory_people = results.get('people', [])
    
    ## I'M SAVING THE NEXT PAGE TOKEN HERE TO USE IN THE WHILE LOOP ##
    next_page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')
    
    for i, person in enumerate(directory_people):
        names = person.get('names', [])
        emails = person.get('emailAddresses',[])
        phones = person.get('phoneNumbers',[])
        orgs = person.get('organizations',[])
        
        ### code to save contacts ###

        with open('file.tsv', 'w') as f:
            f.write("Name\tOrg\tPhone\tEmail\n")
            f.write(f"{name}\t{org}\t{phone}\t{email}\n")

    while next_page_token:
        results = service.people().listDirectoryPeople(
            readMask='names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,organizations',
            sources=src,
            pageSize=1000,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()

        directory_people = results.get('people', [])
        next_page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')
        print(next_page_token)

        for i, person in enumerate(directory_people):
            names = person.get('names', [])
            emails = person.get('emailAddresses',[])
            phones = person.get('phoneNumbers',[])
            orgs = person.get('organizations',[])
            
            ### same code to save contacts ###

            with open('file.tsv', 'a+') as f:
                f.write(f"{name}\t{org}\t{phone}\t{email}\n")
```

The subsequent pages are loaded using `next_page_token` in a while loop.

The problem I'm facing is that the list returned is slightly different every time. E.g. Running the script 3 times would result in 3 different lists of lengths like 20, 25, 18.

Most of the contacts are the same, but there are some which weren't there in the previous run, while some from the previous run are not present now.

*Note: I've used source* `DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT` *too but it doesn't serve my purpose because the contacts I'm interested in aren't available on this source*

*I've also tried using* `people.connections().list()` *method but that simply returns None for my work email*

Does anyone know why the method isn't returning all the contacts like it's supposed to (or at least I believe it's supposed to)?

Comment: Could you also include the code where you use the  `next_page_token`?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've edited it in the question now. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Not getting correct list because with open statement is inside the directory_people list for loop, move this out of loop like this:

```
## I'M SAVING THE NEXT PAGE TOKEN HERE TO USE IN THE WHILE LOOP ##
next_page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')

with open('file.tsv', 'w') as f:
   f.write("Name\tOrg\tPhone\tEmail\n")
   for i, person in enumerate(directory_people):
            name = person.get('names', [])
            email = person.get('emailAddresses',[])
            phone = person.get('phoneNumbers',[])
            org = person.get('organizations',[])
            f.write(f"{name}\t{org}\t{phone}\t{email}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the loop to make it more readable, and not duplicating code;

```
    finished = False
    next_page_token = None
    directory_people = []
    while not finished:
        
        results = service.people().listDirectoryPeople(
            readMask='names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,organizations',
            sources=src,
            pageSize=1000,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()

        result = results.get('people', [])
        directory_people.extend(result)

        next_page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')

        finished = (next_page_token is None)
```